# I would like to Know whether this is a dataset, datagridview or list view and also would like to know how to make on like this

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

[image]

I would like to Know whether this is a dataset, datagridview or list view and also would like to know how to make on like this

Comment: If you have varialbe `a` and want to know is this `DataSet` check
`a is DataSet` for `true`/`false`.

Comment: please update you question to have proper formatting and working link names etc... very ugly question.

Answer (score 0):

`DataSet` =>  The data that you use to attach to the grid.  Will itself contain a collection of `DataTable`

`DataGridView` => The control that shows the data.  Is effectively a collection of column templates, and using those will marry up to the `DataTable` or `DataSet` you set as the DataSource to the control.

`ListView` => These are the repeater controls you can use like a drop down list, they display elements of a collection via a template for each item, allowing the user to select/focus an item or multiples thereof.

To make one like the one you showed, you can use WinForms, which is probably the easiest to learn too!  There's a million resources on the internet for this, Google is your friend, and I'll give you a headstart [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control).

To directly answer your first question, it's actually ***ALL THREE*** of those things!